# cannot get ajax to work, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Some jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: "myAJAX.html",
           success: function(data) {
           $("#ajaxDiv").html(data);
           }
    });
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Click me</button>
    <div id="ajaxDiv">&nbsp;</div>         
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to put alert function on various places in the code, and it seems that AJAX part is not working. I read questions on Stack Overflow, searched on internet, but to no avail. I tried the code with URL of http://ipaddress/mypage.html and I had server with that IP installed on my laptop.
I was previously able to do AJAX calls, without server installed, but when I introduced jQuery, like in above code, nothing happens. Div content stays the same, i.e. empty. I tried to pull .txt file instead of .html, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you view your network tab in your developer tools? you can see where the request was made and what the response was. What happens when you visit myajax.html ?

Comment: I viewed network tab and it showed nothing interesting. Status 304 for file that I requested from CDN. myajax.html is local file. And the code which I posted is in local file too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is your url setting.

```
url: "myAJAX.html"
```

This should point to the url that is the web api you're trying to call. Something like this.

```
url: "/myService/GetStuff"
```

If your myAJAX.html does contain the actual service code can you post that too?

Comment: HTML page in which I make AJAX call and myAJAX.html page, are in the same folder, on local computer. So path is, I suppose, correct. Just file name is needed, right? In myAJAX.html page, there is only <p>Some paragraph.</p>. I tried with page that contains full HTML code, <!DOCTYPE html> and all....also tried page with only a sentence in it, without any HTML tags. I really don't see any problem with code.

Answer (score 0):

Status `304` means the resource was cached,so add `cache:false` to prevent cache

```
   $.ajax({
           url: "myAJAX.html",
           cache:false,
           success: function(data) {
           $("#ajaxDiv").html(data);
           }
    });
```

Comment: it displays status 304 for the line <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>. Status is not related to myAJAX.html.

Comment: @Darko also need to prevent cache from it,you can add `"?time="+new Date()` to prevent cache

Comment: where to put "?time="+new Date()  ?

Comment: like this `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?time="+new Date();></script> `

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $.ajax(), I used the following line, to get myAJAX.html to load into div that has "ajaxDiv" ID.

```
$("#ajaxDiv").load("myAJAX.html");
```

Also, I use the following code, to do the same, and it works, at least on surface.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fetch API</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="fetchMe()">Click me</button>
        <div id="ajaxDiv">&nbsp;</div>

        <script>            
        function fetchMe() {
          fetch("myAJAX.html")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
               document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML = data;
             });
        }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Tell me if there is anything wrong with both code pieces.